# Using Roles and Claims together in ASP.NET Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

The question is: can I use roles and claims together?
At this moment application has roles like: teacher, student, parent. Could I use claims like: create, read, update, delete for each role?
This means that I want to allow some teachers to do everything with Lessons, but some teachers can only read Lessons.
What is the best way to resolve the task?

Comment: Yes, you should have  a look at Row level permissions
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669076(v=vs.110).aspx

You should also read about Role level security - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479759.aspx

Comment: I know mechanism, but I don't know right way to realise this on ASP.NET, the question should I use Claims and Role classes? Or here's some another solution.

Comment: I think you should translate the role as a claim when the user session is established. You seem to know the mapping, so it should be relatively simple to map, say Role{teacher} => Claim{write}.